# What return will await() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning Coroutines of Kotlin. The Code A will get the Result A.

I know *"async is used to start a coroutine that computes some result. The result is represented by an instance of Deferred.".*

So `val one` will return `Deferred`, but what return will `one.await()`?  It seem that `one.await()` will return `Int`, right?

**Code A**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.*

fun main() = runBlocking {

    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = async { doJob1() }       
        val two = async { doJob2() }
        val a1=one.await()
        val a2=two.await()
        println("[testSequential] Result ${a1+a2}")
    }   
    println("[testSequential] Completed in $time ms")   
}

suspend fun doJob1(): Int {
    println("Job1 doing")
    delay(2000L) 
    println("Job1 done")
    return 10
}

suspend fun doJob2(): Int {
    println("Job2 doing")
    delay(1000L) 
    println("Job2 done")
    return 20
}
```

**Result A**

```
Job1 doing
Job2 doing
Job2 done
Job1 done
[testSequential] Result 30
[testSequential] Completed in 2016 ms
```

Comment: Your wording "`val one` will return `Deferred`" is a bit odd. I'd rather say "`one` is an instance of `Deferred`" or "`one` is of type `Deferred`". Other than that, your example seems to answer your own question.

Comment: As a slight amendment to Ulrich's comment, it matters what the type parameter is; "`one` is of type `Deferred<Int>`", not just `Deferred`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to look at [the signature](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/index.html):

```
// in Deferred<T>
abstract suspend fun await(): T
```

So when called on a `Deferred<Int>` it will indeed return `Int`; when called on, say, a `Deferred<YourVeryUsefulClass>` it will return `YourVeryUsefulClass`.

Answer (score 3):

According to `kotlin Document`

`async` starts a separate coroutine which is a light-weight thread that works concurrently with all the other coroutines.

`async` returns a Deferred — a light-weight non-blocking future that represents a promise to provide a result later.

**You can use `.await()` on a deferred value to get its eventual result, but Deferred is also a Job, so you can cancel it if needed.**

let's say

```
val one = async { Fun() } 
//one is type of Deferred 
val mystring = one.await()
//mystring is type of string

fun Fun(): String{
    return "hello"
}
```

Comment: `fun` in this example does not have to be `suspend`